Structural Vector Autoregression: proof of the $(^2−)/2$ restrictions and identifiability?
I'm currently using Structural vector autoregressive models by Kevin Kotzé to learn Vector Autoregression. One of the points that it makes is the following:

the number of restrictions that we need to impose is equivalent to the number of terms in the lower (or upper) triangle of the B matrix, which is $(K^2-K)/2$

where our model is the following VAR(1) ($y_t$ is a K-dimensional vector of variables):
$B y_t = \Gamma_0 + \Gamma_1 y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$, which leads to the following reduced-form VAR:
$y_t = A_0 + A_1 y_{t-1} + u_t$
In the bivariate case, this seems to make sense as with $K=2$, we can easily solve the system of equations and find all the structural VAR parameters. However, it's not totally obvious to me:
a) Why $(K^2-K)/2$ is the magic number that allows us to deduce the structural parameters - I understand it is equivalent to the upper triangle of B.
b) How we know that given this amount of restrictions, we can always solve for all the structural parameters. I calculated by hand and was able to convince myself for $K=2$, but it's not immediately obvious that higher dimensions will follow similarly.
I'm wondering if there are any proofs or more rigorous illustrations as to why this result can be true for all $K$.
 See also the answer I got on Economics Stack Exchange. 

Update: Per the warning on stackexchange, I decided not to delete my original post on economics.stackexchange.com as the answer had 3 upvotes from other people and may be helpful to them, but since my question was not answered, I hope I can repost here (let me know if it is ok)

I think the answer provided on Economic Stack Exchange is not right. Hence, I have provided an answer here.

louki: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense. Do you know if, in  a structural var, are any of the covariances set to zero like in a recursive var or are all they all non-zero.

The identification of a structural vector autoregression (SVAR) boils down to finding the $K \times K$ matrix $B$, or equivalently $B^{-1}$. Then it follows that $\Gamma_0 = B A_0$ and $\Gamma_1 = B A_1$.
As you've rightly noticed, the number of elements in the matrix $B$ are $K^2$. Furthermore, assuming that your reduced-form innovations follow a Gaussian distribution, e.g., $u_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, we know that $\Sigma=B^{-1}(B^{-1})'$ holds. We know that $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix and thus symmetric. This means we have $K$ variances and $(K-1)K/2$ covariances available to identify $K^2$ elements in $B$. The rest ist just counting:
$K^2 - K - \frac{(K-1)K}{2} = \frac{2K^2-2K-K^2+K}{2} = \frac{K^2-K}{2}$.
For instance, for a $3 \times 3$ matrix, we have the symmetric matrix
$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{31} \\ \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} & \sigma_{32} \\ \sigma_{31} & \sigma_{32} & \sigma_{33}\end{bmatrix}$,
where $(\sigma_{11}, \sigma_{22}, \sigma_{33})'$ denote $K=3$ variances and $(\sigma_{21}, \sigma_{31}, \sigma_{32})'$ denote $K=(K-1)K/2=3$ covariances.
This holds equivalently for higher dimensions. I think the important insight is to realize that this follows from the symmetry in covariance matrix which provides you with two sets of parameters you can already exploit: variances and covariances. However, those do not suffice to provide exact identification. (Note that there are also methods for partial identification - see for instance the literature on sign-restrictions).
I should also add at this point that even exact identification is not exactly exact. Still, this is dependent upon a sign and scale convention.
